# Passing a string type variable to POST call in restangular

Tags: angularjs, post, restangular

I have to pass a string parameter to API call mentioned below

```
assetsComments.attachFile(Restangular, response.CommentUID).post(fileResponse[0]).then(function (response) {})
```

Here type of fileResponse[0] must be string.
I checked the type and it is string, but i am getting error 400 (argument cannot be null).

I have also checked the same API on DHC and while passing fileUID(fileResponse[0] in above call) when i pass it in double quotes ("fileUID") it works fine, but if I pass it without double quotes (fileUID) it gives me same error 400 (argument cannot be null).

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Issue solved......just concatenated doube quotes before and after the variable eg- '"' + variable +'"' .

Comment: Or maybe use String(fileResponse[0]); http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating a string with double quotes is not safe as it may already contain them. It's better to use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
Restangular.all('words').post(JSON.stringify(myStringVariable));
```